# Pandas - dividing each cell by column sum - But it returns the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I encountered a very strange (and frustrating) issue with Pandas.
I want to divide each cell in the dataframe by the sum of the column. I have already googled and used the answer suggested but it doesn't work - the contents of each row returns the SAME VALUE.

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(3,3)), columns=['A','B','C'])
# Now here is the copied solution from google
dfs = dfs.div(dfs.sum(axis=0),axis=1)
```

So for easy examples like above it works very well. But the moment I tried it on my dataframe, which has 1080 columns, every row has the same value.
[image]

I have made sure to drop all nan, inf, or anything other than numbers, and the dtype for all the columns is float64. I am not sure why this is happening, could anyone give me some ideas what is wrong? I have a feeling that it is because of the size of the dataframe? But surely 1080 columns and 8 rows shouldn't be too much for Pandas to handle?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Yes, run this code to get the first 2 columns of my dataframe.

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame({'7006091':[2.219749271,2.15577658,1.857604216,
1.588101736,
0.925926932,
1.413871811,
1.528702513,
1.313778722
],'7007772':[2.21238513,
2.148624672,
1.851441511,
1.582833121,
0.922855119,
1.409181214,
1.523630958,
1.309420189
]})
```

I just tried dfs.update as suggested and it didn't work either. This is what was returned with:

```
dfs.update(dfs.div(dfs.sum(axis=0),axis=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your original dfs , just two columns

Comment: Post updated! This is incomprehensible - I am getting feeling some pandas file got corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you have the same output , since your columns have the same distribution ,check out

```
dfs['7006091']/dfs['7007772']
0    1.003329
1    1.003329
2    1.003329
3    1.003329
4    1.003329
5    1.003329
6    1.003329
7    1.003329
dtype: float64
```

So they are just same value after we standarlized with column `sum`

Answer (score 1):

IICU

```
dfs.update(dfs.div(dfs.sum(axis=0),axis=1))
dfs
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it didn't work out, I have updated my post...

Comment: What version are you using? What error did it give you? Looks like it is working for me unless I didnt get you right. Please see my edits

Comment: My pandas version is 1.0.1
Hold on - your results not right as well? The 2 columns should not be exactly the same?

Comment: Same version. Is the output answer I just posted what you want? and what error does it give you when you run?

Comment: No I will try to give example output 1 second

Comment: Yoben found out the problem... I was an idiot! Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Happy, That is an experienced hand